# Last component of User Control doesn't fill the available space on the hosting grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a C# wpf project and I am having an issue. I have a Main Window which hosts a grid. This grid hosts a User Control and the User Control hosts 3 DockPanels in a 3 column layout.

The 3 columns are adjustable via a grid splitter which is working however, the right hand side column isn't filling the available space of the Main Window grid.

Below is the XAML of my Main Window hosting the user control:

```
<Window x:Class="Boardies_Email_Client.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Boardies_Email_Client"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="GridHost" Margin="0" Background="#FFF3FF00"/>
        <StatusBar Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Below is the XAML for the User Control

```
<UserControl x:Class="Boardies_Email_Client.EmailClient"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Boardies_Email_Client"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="505">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1120">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="92*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="121*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="87*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="225*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="134*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="116*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="345*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Background="#FFEC1717" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Label x:Name="label" Content="My Label" Margin="0,0,0,460" Width="175"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <GridSplitter x:Name="gridSplitter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="5" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" Margin="5,0,0,0" Background="#FF5DFF00" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
        <GridSplitter x:Name="gridSplitter1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="5" Grid.Column="5"/>
        <DockPanel Grid.Column="5" Margin="5,0,0,0" Background="#FF0A00E2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Below is a screenshot showing the problem

[image: Screenshot showing problem]

The red, green and blue are the dock panels separated by grid splitters. The yellow is the background colour of the the grid of the main window hosting the user control, the blue panel should be filling up the available space of the yellow but I can't see why it isn't.

I haven't hard set any widths that I can find.

Comment: You could bind the width of the columns with a converter to divide the grid's width by the number of the columns.

Comment: The grid inside the usercontrol has fixed widht. If you want to stretch to the window, remove horizontalalignment and widht

Answer (score 0):

@Boardy

I ran your code. 
The splitting of the UserControl and organization of the Grid are fine.

But you set the width to a fixed size :

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1120">
```

If you remove the fixed size, everything is fine, the control takes the size of the window and you don't see other background (yellow or right) on the right for sizes larger than 1120 :

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid >
```

Regards